# how can i add height constraint

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have this layout for my iphone app (image 1). Now what I want to do is add a *constraint* to second *stack view* such that my stack view tree would look like image 2. Now the problem is that whenever i try to add the constraint by clicking on the bottom bar of UI designer in XCode, it does add the constraint but then i see conflicts with parents constraints and hence XCode ask me to remove either 1 or multiple constraints. How can i add this constraint successfully?

(Sorry i don't know the UI Components name for XCode to refer them properly)

**image 1**

[image: image 1]

**image 2**

[image: image 2]

Comment: Are you sure StackView is what you want here? Please read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview) to be sure. I didn't have the issue you described building your desired hierarchy. More details would be helpful. What parents constraints are conflicting? What constraints do you have for stack views?

Comment: I am following Udemy NanoDegree tutorial where this is what i have asked to do. I have already spent time looking at their forums, documentation but nothing helped. The parent constraints are visible at the bottom of the first image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to change UIStackView's `alignment` property. If you have it set to `fill` StackView tries to stretch Button while you set its width to 64. That probably causes the conflicts.
[image]

The same goes for the height. Make sure `distribution` property doesn't contradict with what you're setting manually.